# I can't manage to remove end if et end for even with the command noend

Tags: algorithms, algorithmicx

i'm using pseudo code in my latex, this is an example of what i'm doing :

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
\caption{A}
\begin{algorithmic} 
\IF{ A}
\STATE \Return B
\ENDIF
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

I read here that using \usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode} would remove the End if and End for from the end result in my algorithms, but they are still appearing in my pdf (actually, i don't see any difference with and without the package \usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}). How can i get rid of this ?

Comment: Sorry, but please extend tend this to an actual example that others can text as is. BTW: I would have expected `inputenc` to be loaded with options (most docs does not need `inputenc` anymore as LaTeX now assumes `utf8` by default)

Comment: here, i changed my question & i tried to put an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *either* use `algorithmic` *or* `algpseudocode`.

Since you seem to prefer the former, don't mix syntax with the latter, so `\RETURN` instead of `\Return`, but no `\STATE`, see the code below.

And use the `noend` option.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[noend]{algorithmic}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
\caption{A}
\begin{algorithmic}
\IF{A}{\RETURN B}
\ENDIF
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Or, with `algpseudocode`,

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
\caption{A}
\begin{algorithmic} 
\If{A}
\State \Return B
\EndIf
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ah merci beaucoup !!